# Fetching a column based on its values from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
   SELECT pn.PhoneId,
       pn.CountryId,
       c.ITUCode,
       pn.AreaCode,
       pn.PhoneNumber,
       pn.PhoneExtension,
       pn.PhoneNumberTypeId,
       pnt.PhoneNumberType,
       pn.Comments,
       ppn.IsPrimaryNumber,
       cpn.IsPrimaryNumber
FROM PhoneNumbers AS pn
INNER JOIN PeoplePhoneNumbers AS ppn ON ppn.PhoneId = pn.PhoneId
INNER JOIN CompanyPhoneNumbers AS cpn ON cpn.PhoneId = pn.PhoneId
INNER JOIN Countries AS c ON c.CountryId = pn.CountryId
INNER JOIN PhoneNumberTypes AS pnt ON pnt.PhoneNumberTypeId = pn.PhoneNumberTypeId
WHERE pn.PhoneId = @PhoneId
ORDER BY ppn.IsPrimaryNumber DESC, pnt.PhoneNumberType
```

Now as you can c to fetch `IsPrimaryKey` I have to use two different `innerjoins` and get two values from it.

One of them would be `null` and other would have a value that is always the case.

So can i change this query to a single `innerjoin` join for both of them and then fetch single `IsPrimaryNumber` field from it and not the other one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` the two tables `ppn`, `cpn` with `COALESCE` to put them in one column, like so:

```
SELECT 
  pn.PhoneId, 
  pn.CountryId, 
  c.ITUCode, 
  pn.AreaCode, 
  pn.PhoneNumber, 
  pn.PhoneExtension,
  pn.PhoneNumberTypeId, 
  pnt.PhoneNumberType, 
  pn.Comments, 
  COALESCE(ppn.IsPrimaryNumber, cpn.IsPrimaryNumber) IsPrimaryNumber
FROM PhoneNumbers AS pn
INNER JOIN Countries          AS c   ON c.CountryId = pn.CountryId
INNER JOIN PhoneNumberTypes   AS pnt 
        ON pnt.PhoneNumberTypeId = pn.PhoneNumberTypeId
LEFT JOIN PeoplePhoneNumbers  AS ppn ON ppn.PhoneId = pn.PhoneId
LEFT JOIN CompanyPhoneNumbers AS cpn ON cpn.PhoneId = pn.PhoneId
WHERE pn.PhoneId = @PhoneId
ORDER BY ppn.IsPrimaryNumber DESC, pnt.PhoneNumberType;
```

Comment: How will coalesce help me in this?
What would be the result of the the following?

Comment: @user1960365 `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE` will give you only one `IsPrimaryNumber`. This will give you the first non nullable `IsPrimaryNumber` from the two table `ppn` and `cpn` into one column.